# Convert list of list of string to list of list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hello I have a list of list of strings which looks like this

```
x = [["and bee cos dup ete", "ans bew coa duo etr"], ["snd nee vos fup rte", "sns new voa fuo rtr"]]
```

I wish to make another list from the strings within the list of lists separated by a space i.e.:

```
x = [[[and,bee,cos,dup,ete], [ans,bew,coa,duo,etr]], [[snd,nee,vos,fup,rte], [sns,new,voa,fuo,rtr]]]
```

I tried

```
for i in x:
    for y in i:
        y.split()
```

But this does not work

Comment: show your desired output

Comment: Do you do anything with your `y`? Where do you create your new list?

Comment: Use a list comprehension :-) `[[s.split() for s in l] for l in x]`

Comment: Note that `y.split()` isn't assingning anything anywhere. You should define a list before the first `for`. And then append to it

Comment: the output is the second "x" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are

```py
x = [["and bee cos dup ete", "ans bew coa duo etr"], ["snd nee vos fup rte", "sns new voa fuo rtr"]]
y = []

for sub in x:
    y.append([])
    for subsub in sub:
        y[-1].append(subsub.split(" "))
    
print(y)
```

**Output:**

```
[[['and', 'bee', 'cos', 'dup', 'ete'], ['ans', 'bew', 'coa', 'duo', 'etr']], [['snd', 'nee', 'vos', 'fup', 'rte'], ['sns', 'new', 'voa', 'fuo', 'rtr']]]
```

**EDIT**
You can also do it this way, with only one `for loop`:

```py
x = [["and bee cos dup ete", "ans bew coa duo etr"], ["snd nee vos fup rte", "sns new voa fuo rtr"]]
y = []

for sub in x:
    y.append([[splitted for splitted in subsub.split(" ")] for subsub in sub])
    
print(y)
```

With the same result

Comment: how?????????????

Comment: It's called "black magic"... Oh no, "comprehensive list" : examples [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

1. General Solution:

   ```
   x=[[j.split(" ") for j in i] for i in x]
   ```
2. For above particular situation

   ```
   x=[[i[0].split(" "),i[1].split(" ")] for i in x]
   ```

**Output:**

```
[[['and', 'bee', 'cos', 'dup', 'ete'], ['ans', 'bew', 'coa', 'duo', 'etr']], [['snd', 'nee', 'vos', 'fup', 'rte'], ['s
ns', 'new', 'voa', 'fuo', 'rtr']]]
```

Comment: hardcoding element index is bad

Comment: Edited @sahasrara62